# Typo3 Extbase: How to sort parent objects by property of child objects

Tags: typo3, extbase

Say I have an extbase extension with parent objects "foo" with an m:n relationship to child objects "bar".
Each "bar" object has an integer property "barNum".
I want to sort my "foo" objects by which one contains a "bar" object with the lowest "barNum" value.
How can I do this?

I can sort by fields of the foo object like:

```
class FooRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository
{
    protected $defaultOrderings = [
        'fooField' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
    ];
    }
```

But I don't see any way to sort by a field of an m:n related child object

---

To clarify: for example, if my data looks like this:

```
"foos": {
    "foo1": {
        "bars": {
            "bar1": {
                "barNum": 31
            },
            "bar2": {
                "barNum": 42
            }
        }
    },
    "foo2": {
        "bars": {
            "bar3": {
                "barNum": 82
            },
            "bar4": {
                "barNum": 19
            }
        }
    },
    "foo3": {
        "bars": {
            "bar5": {
                "barNum": 37
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would want it sorted *foo2, foo1, foo3*, because 19 < 31 < 37.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by sub objects and properties by using the `.`, e.g. `fooFieldWithObject.barField`.

In your case I'd try: `bars.barNum`

```php
class FooRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository
{
    protected $defaultOrderings = [
        'bars.barNum' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is working for me.
So I suppose when it sorts via ORDER_ASCENDING, it will automatically use the lowest subobject property value available for each object.
Hypothetically, what if someone wanted to sort ascending via the highest subobject value? So in the example above, foo3, foo1, foo2, since 37 < 42 < 82.